# Missing fields in json extraction

Tags: python, arrays, json, parsing

I am facing an issue with missing fields in json extraction. following is how my json looks like:

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "id": "f7w0KvbCMln8snSrNuPm5H2t2GSZY",
            "location_id": "8V3SAM09X4AQF",
            "line_items": [
                {
                    "uid": "1",
                    "catalog_object_id": "EBUX2MILP4UJ76CEE5MBIQJA",
                    "catalog_version": 1681426511907,
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "name": "Minh's roll",
                    "variation_name": "Regular",
                    "base_price_money": {
                        "amount": 725,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "note": "",
                    "gross_sales_money": {
                        "amount": 725,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "total_tax_money": {
                        "amount": 36,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "total_discount_money": {
                        "amount": 0,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "total_money": {
                        "amount": 761,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "variation_total_price_money": {
                        "amount": 725,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "applied_taxes": [
                        {
                            "uid": "OLSBPOGb776jAh7GfxfTq",
                            "tax_uid": "9",
                            "applied_money": {
                                "amount": 36,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "item_type": "ITEM",
                    "total_service_charge_money": {
                        "amount": 0,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "uid": "2",
                    "catalog_object_id": "FBKFLKQHT5DQXA7C2BOOA7QZ",
                    "catalog_version": 1681426511907,
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "name": "Royal Milk Tea",
                    "variation_name": "Regular",
                    "base_price_money": {
                        "amount": 550,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "modifiers": [
                        {
                            "uid": "3",
                            "base_price_money": {
                                "amount": 50,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_price_money": {
                                "amount": 50,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "name": "Tapioca Pearls",
                            "catalog_object_id": "D3JB47IY6ZMBSNNUCYRBVCP6",
                            "catalog_version": 1681426511907,
                            "quantity": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "4",
                            "base_price_money": {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_price_money": {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "name": "1/2 Sugar",
                            "catalog_object_id": "L634LGNPEUWPGY3KA6CPZ6RH",
                            "catalog_version": 1681426511907,
                            "quantity": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "uid": "5",
                            "base_price_money": {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_price_money": {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "name": "1/2 Ice",
                            "catalog_object_id": "GPISTPCC76ZPISXD7WDZQ6RJ",
                            "catalog_version": 1681426511907,
                            "quantity": "1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "note": "",
                    "gross_sales_money": {
                        "amount": 600,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "total_tax_money": {
                        "amount": 30,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "total_discount_money": {
                        "amount": 0,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "total_money": {
                        "amount": 630,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "variation_total_price_money": {
                        "amount": 550,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "applied_taxes": [
                        {
                            "uid": "vZUmVv8HhcYV9j1hvfDCJ",
                            "tax_uid": "9",
                            "applied_money": {
                                "amount": 30,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "item_type": "ITEM",
                    "total_service_charge_money": {
                        "amount": 0,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "uid": "6",
                    "catalog_object_id": "PGMSZP2KCPT4BPJVRND2Y7TZ",
                    "catalog_version": 1681426511907,
                    "quantity": "2",
                    "name": "Pho Ga",
                    "variation_name": "Regular",
                    "base_price_money": {
                        "amount": 1650,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "modifiers": [
                        {
                            "uid": "7",
                            "base_price_money": {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_price_money": {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "name": "Rice Noodles",
                            "catalog_object_id": "THNRPUH447QAPTCPL5ZMJU5E",
                            "catalog_version": 1681426511907,
                            "quantity": "1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "note": "",
                    "gross_sales_money": {
                        "amount": 3300,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "total_tax_money": {
                        "amount": 165,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "total_discount_money": {
                        "amount": 0,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "total_money": {
                        "amount": 3465,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "variation_total_price_money": {
                        "amount": 3300,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "applied_taxes": [
                        {
                            "uid": "8jLMPWQ0ihC3C9x48dq6LD",
                            "tax_uid": "9",
                            "applied_money": {
                                "amount": 165,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "item_type": "ITEM",
                    "total_service_charge_money": {
                        "amount": 0,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "taxes": [
                {
                    "uid": "9",
                    "name": "Delivery Tax",
                    "percentage": "4.995",
                    "type": "ADDITIVE",
                    "applied_money": {
                        "amount": 231,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "scope": "ORDER"
                }
            ],
            "fulfillments": [
                {
                    "uid": "8",
                    "type": "PICKUP",
                    "state": "COMPLETED",
                    "pickup_details": {
                        "pickup_at": "2023-04-13T23:35:13.000Z",
                        "note": "Delivery by Doordash\nNOTE: Lisa B",
                        "placed_at": "2023-04-13T23:21:10.883Z",
                        "accepted_at": "2023-04-14T03:30:25.315Z",
                        "ready_at": "2023-04-14T03:30:25.315Z",
                        "schedule_type": "ASAP",
                        "recipient": {
                            "display_name": "Lisa B",
                            "phone_number": "+12497022887",
                            "address": {
                                "address_line_1": "",
                                "administrative_district_level_1": "",
                                "first_name": "Lisa",
                                "last_name": "B"
                            }
                        },
                        "picked_up_at": "2023-04-14T03:30:25.315Z"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2023-04-13T23:21:10.037Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-04-14T03:30:25.316Z",
            "state": "COMPLETED",
            "version": 6,
            "reference_id": "a629b6f6",
            "total_tax_money": {
                "amount": 231,
                "currency": "CAD"
            },
            "total_discount_money": {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "CAD"
            },
            "total_tip_money": {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "CAD"
            },
            "total_money": {
                "amount": 4856,
                "currency": "CAD"
            },
            "closed_at": "2023-04-14T03:30:25.316Z",
            "tenders": [
                {
                    "id": "LdwMfHKagHGPC4TWfaonReYjL0GZY",
                    "location_id": "8V3SAM09X4AQF",
                    "transaction_id": "hi9NAJ3prjwsHf2v8feSkNiZhp8YY",
                    "created_at": "2023-04-13T23:21:10Z",
                    "amount_money": {
                        "amount": 4856,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "type": "OTHER",
                    "tip_money": {
                        "amount": 0,
                        "currency": "CAD"
                    },
                    "payment_id": "LdwMfHKagHGPC4TWfaonReYjL0GZY"
                }
            ],
            "total_service_charge_money": {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "CAD"
            },
            "net_amounts": {
                "total_money": {
                    "amount": 4856,
                    "currency": "CAD"
                },
                "tax_money": {
                    "amount": 231,
                    "currency": "CAD"
                },
                "discount_money": {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "currency": "CAD"
                },
                "tip_money": {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "currency": "CAD"
                },
                "service_charge_money": {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "currency": "CAD"
                }
            },
            "source": {
                "name": "DoorDash"
            },
            "net_amount_due_money": {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": "CAD"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "r9EV9dqgCtFTKxvxLLDOuV7m5DeZY",
            "location_id": "8V3SAM09X4AQF",
            "created_at": "2023-04-13T23:15:17.925Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-04-13T23:15:19.000Z",
            "state": "COMPLETED",
            "version": 4,
            "closed_at": "2023-04-13T23:15:18.273Z",
            "returns": [
                {
                    "uid": "7m4NHLUPMLkTmuLhtPkMRD",
                    "source_order_id": "PfyOwZLVSnNwKmhYwhNiSgVs7QeZY",
                    "return_line_items": [
                        {
                            "uid": "NeX5lw1mdclSazsaAFXzdB",
                            "quantity": "1",
                            "item_type": "CUSTOM_AMOUNT",
                            "base_price_money": {
                                "amount": 3678,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "variation_total_price_money": {
                                "amount": 3678,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "gross_return_money": {
                                "amount": 3678,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_tax_money": {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_discount_money": {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_money": {
                                "amount": 3678,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            },
                            "total_service_charge_money": {
                                "amount": 0,
                                "currency": "CAD"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the following:

```
print("Started Reading JSON file")
with open("SQUARE_order.json", "r") as read_file:
print("Converting JSON encoded data into Python dictionary")`
data = json.load(read_file)
for order in data['orders']:
  for item in order['line_items']:
    for mod in modifiers:
      print((order['id'],item['name'],mod['name'], mod['catalog_object_id'], item['base_price_money']))
```

For example I want to extract: but with the above logic it doesnt give the outcome.

Please help: "id": "hi9NAJ3prjwsHf2v8feSkNiZhp8YY" I want to extract: "name": "Tapioca Pearls",               "catalog_object_id": "D3JB47IY6ZMBSNNUCYRBVCP6".

Comment: "I am facing an issue with missing fields in json extraction." - please provide the error/s you are receiving.

Comment: I have formatted your code correctly to the best of my ability, but it was very unclear to begin with. Please review and revise if the formatting has changed your code inadvertently.

Comment: I dont have a error as such. just that few items I am not able to extract: For example :catalog_object_id": "D3JB47IY6ZMBSNNUCYRBVCP6" and the relative name for it

Comment: When you say you want to extract, what data are you attempting to extract specifically? Are you simply attempting to index into the JSON to retrieve that specific object? Or are you looking for a more general method to identity an object by name/id and return it?

Comment: general method to identity an object by name/id and return it

Comment: Doable, but keep in mind "Tapioca Pearls" is considered a `modifier` to a `line_item` of an `order` based on the JSON structure. So in this case, you'd be searching for a specific modifier. Should the result be the `line_item` or the `modifier`?

Comment: Modifier result

Comment: @h0r53 Is there a way I can add to existing code.

Comment: I have provided an answer with code that achieves what you are asking. Feel free to modify it if you need. If that answer resolves your problem, consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer such that it should now fully resolve your issue in Python, no edits needed. Please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Python script that will attempt to return the `modifier` of a `line_item` in an `order` by matching the `catalog_object_id`.

```py
import json
print("Started Reading JSON file")
with open("SQUARE_order.json", "r") as read_file:
    print("Converting JSON encoded data into Python dictionary")
    data = json.load(read_file)

def find_modifier(catalog_object_id, order_object):
    if "orders" in order_object:
        for order in order_object["orders"]:
            if "line_items" in order:
                for item in order["line_items"]:
                    if "modifiers" in item:
                        for modifier in item["modifiers"]:
                            if modifier["catalog_object_id"] == catalog_object_id:
                                return modifier
    print(f"Modifier not found for catalog object ID: {catalog_object_id}")


modifier = find_modifier("D3JB47IY6ZMBSNNUCYRBVCP6", data)
if modifier:
    print(modifier)
```

Result:

```json
Started Reading JSON file
Converting JSON encoded data into Python dictionary
{'uid': '3', 'base_price_money': {'amount': 50, 'currency': 'CAD'}, 'total_price_money': {'amount': 50, 'currency': 'CAD'}, 'name': 'Tapioca Pearls', 'catalog_object_id': 'D3JB47IY6ZMBSNNUCYRBVCP6', 'catalog_version': 1681426511907, 'quantity': '1'}
```

Comment: @Aiss I'm glad this worked for you. Please consider Accepting the answer so I receive credit. Thanks!